# Sizeof this pointer in cpp

Tags: c++, gcc, sizeof

I found that the output of this answer varies from the version of the gcc compiler used.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class ABC{

  int x;

public:

  void show(){

    cout<<sizeof (this);

    cout<<sizeof (*this);

  }
};

int main(){

  ABC ob;
  ob.show();
  return 0;
}
```

This code gives the output of 84 in the version 4.9.1 and the same gives the 44 in the previous version.

Can any one clearly explain me what the concept is behind the "this" pointer?

Comment: Apparently, one time you compiled a 32bit program, and now a 64bit program. Pointer size: 4 byte vs 8 byte.

Comment: `no both the times I have compiled it in the 64bit` I don´t believe you that, because a 4byte pointer makes absolutely no sense then. Maybe, on some exotic platform, pointers can be too large, but never too small. And you´ll surely find it in the codeblocks config.

Comment: As remyabel wrote in his answer already, `-m32` or `-m64`. If neither is specified, the default value depends on your GCC build. Where to find this in the CodeBlocks Gui: http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php?title=Developing_32_bit_apps_under_64_bit_Linux_%28Ubuntu%29#Setting_the_build_options_in_Code::Blocks

Comment: after a little bit searching i found that codeblocks uses 32 bit compiler so I should blame codeblocks and not gcc for different answers :) thx for ur ans @deviantfan

Comment: Did you read the link? You can configure what CodeBlock uses, separately for each project.

Comment: yes @deviantfan also this links explains it how to make it as gcc 64 bit one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `this` pointer is defined in N3337 [class.this]:

> `1` In the body of a non-static (9.3) member function, the keyword
>   `this` is a prvalue expression whose value is the address of the
>   object for which the function is called. The type of `this` in a
>   member function of a class `X` is `X*`.

So there's nothing special about `sizeof(this)`. As pointed out by [deviantfan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27400267/sizeof-this-pointer-in-cpp#comment43246107_27400267), more than likely you are observing the effect of compiling a 32-bit program versus a 64-bit program.

GCC with `-m32` outputs `44` and `84` without.

Comment: after a little bit searching i found that codeblocks uses 32 bit compiler so I should blame codeblocks and not gcc for different answers :) thx for ur ans @remyabel

Answer (score 0):

Class is template which is not assigned any space in heap memory. Once you created a variable ob in main() function, memory is allocated to variable ob in heap memory based on definition of the class. There is also a header space to the memory location that contains metadata of the variable. "this" contains the address of the allocated memory.

Now different versions of compilers deal this memory allocation differently.

Look at the functions in the class definition. Those are same across all instances of variable of type ABC. So a version may allocated a shared space for functions where as another may allocated space for functions for each instance eating more space.

This could be one of the reason behind differences.